# Create Map from Option of List

Tags: scala, list-comprehension

I'm trying to create a map from an option of list. So, I have an option of list declared like this:

`val authHeaders: Option[Set[String]] = Some(Set("a", "b", "c"))`

and I want to get a map like this: (a -> a, b -> b, c -> c).

So I tried this way:

```
for {
  headers <- authHeaders
  header <- headers
} yield (header -> header)
```

But I get this error:

```
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[(String, String)]
required: Option[?]
             header <- headers
                    ^
```

Where did I do wrong?

Additional note: this Option thing has been giving me quite a headache, but I need to understand how to deal with it in any case. Anyway, just for comparison, I tried removing the headache factor, by removing the Option.

```
scala> val bah = Set("a", "b", "c")
bah: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(a, b, c)

scala> (
     | for {
     | x <- bah
     | } yield (x -> x)).toMap
res36: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a -> a, b -> b, c -> c)
```

So, apparently it works. What is the difference here?

Additional note:

Looks like the rule of the game for the "for comprehension" here: if it produces something, that something must be of the same type of the outer collection (in this case that of authHeaders, which is an Option[?]). How to work around it?

Thanks!,
Raka

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The Problem**

Your `for` gets desugared into:

```
authHeaders.flatMap(headers => headers.map(header => header -> header))
```

The problem in this case is the usage of `flatMap`, because `authHeaders` is an `Option`.
Lets have a look at the signature. (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.Option)

```
final def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ Option[B]): Option[B]
```

So the function `f` is expected to return an `Option`. But `authHeaders.map(header => header -> header)` is not an `Option` and therefore you get an error.

**A solution**

Assuming that if `authHeaders` is `None` you want an empty `Map`, we can use `fold`.

```
authHeaders.fold(Map.empty[String, String])(_.map(s => s -> s).toMap)
```

The first parameter is the result if `authHeaders` is `None`. The second is expected to be a function `Set[String] => Map[String, String]` and gets evaluated if there is some `Set`.

In case you want to keep the result in an `Option` and just want to have a `Map` when there actually is some `Set`, you can simply use `map`.

```
authHeaders.map(_.map(s => s -> s).toMap)
```

**Regarding your additional Note**

This is the signature of `flatMap` on `TraversableOnce`. (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableOnce)

```
def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]): TraversableOnce[B]
```

Here `f` can return any collection that is an instance of `GenTraversableOnce`.

So things like this are possible: `Set(1,2,3).flatMap(i => List(i))` (not really a creative example, I know..)

I see `Option` as a special case.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works.  Now I'm trying to cram the meaning of folding (and its difference from reduce) :) Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to generalise this. I assume this solution should work for any iterable (not just Option). So I modified the declaration of authHeaders to: scala> val authHeaders: Set[Set[String]] = `Set(Set("a", "b", "c"), Set("d", "e"))
authHeaders: Set[Set[String]] = Set(Set(a, b, c), Set(d, e))`.... and I'm expecting a map like this (a->a, b->b, c->c, d->d, e->e).... But... instead, I'm getting an error that says: error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 2 ... Something is not right in the way I understand the solution you gave me (or my understanding of fold)..

Comment: I used the `fold` on `authHeaders` (as an `Option`). Your `authHeaders` is not an `Option`. You can just work with for-comprehension or `map`/`flatMap` here. Either `(for(set <- authHeaders; s <- set) yield (s -> s)).toMap` or equivalently `authHeaders.flatMap(_.map(s => s -> s)).toMap`